# what is the unit of measurement for distance of esri function ST_Distance returns? and how to get it in meters/Kilometers

Tags: geospatial, spatial, hadoop2, esri

i am using

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ST_Distance
  AS 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.ST_Distance';

SELECT ST_Distance(st_geomfromtext((GEOMETRY_STR)),(st_point(17.3864612476915,78.4119865215241))) as dist
FROM routeDF
WHERE ID = 'NH04';
```

distance.show returned "0.005588125384800691". i am not sure what is this value and i need this in kilometer or meters.

Comment: Don't tag random stuff in there. This has nothing to do with PostGIS.

Answer (score 1):

The output unit is the same as the input unit with `ST_Distance` - for example, meters in meters out, or degrees in degrees out.
You may be interested in utilizing `ST_GeodesicLengthWGS84` with a temporary two-vertex linestring.
[disclosure: collaborator]

Comment: than u for the info, but i want to find the distance between the point and the geometric area in meters/kms.please let me know how to do this. For example: sqlContext.sql("""SELECT ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText((GEOMETRY_STR)),st_point(Longitude,Latitude)) as distance from table1 where  ID = '41427' """)

Comment: See `ST_GeodesicLengthWGS84`.

Comment: hi Randall, i have gone through this but really not able to find how to get the distance between a polygon and the point with lat,long as i said above. Please help me in this. Example: POLYGON((17.577459024528 78.3085446904473,17.5340675540023 78.3040506640145,17.4872547570143 78.3013696327098,........)) and point (Longitu‌​de,Latitude)

Comment: Ah, polygon (ideally that would be clearly mentioned in the original question).  See ideas in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185494/proximity-query-in-hive-using-esri-geospatial-library.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Qs. So started digging... [from here](https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/esri/core/geometry/OperatorDistanceLocal.java) and [reached here](https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/esri/core/geometry/Point2D.java)

Looks like this is the distance computation formula!

```
public static double sqrDistance(Point2D pt1, Point2D pt2) {
    double dx = pt1.x - pt2.x;
    double dy = pt1.y - pt2.y;
    return dx * dx + dy * dy;
}
```

It must be doing a sqrt before returning the results. I ran the following in AWS Athena/Presto -

```
ST_DISTANCE(ST_POINT(48.64703, -122.26324), ST_POINT(48.6721, -122.265)) = 0.025131703085942852

sqrt((48.64703-48.6721)^2 + (-122.26324+122.265)^2) = 0.02513170309
```

Looks like the answer matches!!

[The answer to the conversion Qs. is here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58653/what-is-approximate-error-of-pythagorean-theorem-vs-haversine-formula-in-measur) i.e. to to get in km you need ...

```
ST_DISTANCE(...) * 6371 * Sqrt[dx^2 + dy^2]] * pi / 180
```

I needed the distance in meters and I did a small test to see if the conversion was close and it turned out to be very close to the m. It differs by decimal places. You need to out your lat longs as an array to see the results.

```
import math
from haversine import haversine
test = [
[lat,lon,lat,lon],
...
[lat,lon,lat,lon]
]

for x in test:
  dist = math.hypot(x[2] - x[0], x[3] - x[1]) * 6371000*math.pi/180
  hv = haversine(x[0:2],x[2:4])*1000
  print('eucledian: %0.3f' %  dist, '\thaversine: %0.3f ' % hv, '\toffset: %0.3f' % (hv - dist),'m')
```

My Results looked like this:

```
eucledian: 0.127    haversine: 0.111    offset: -0.015 m
eucledian: 0.273    haversine: 0.219    offset: -0.053 m
eucledian: 1.875    haversine: 1.715    offset: -0.159 m
eucledian: 2.460    haversine: 2.387    offset: -0.073 m
eucledian: 0.961    haversine: 0.881    offset: -0.080 m
eucledian: 0.099    haversine: 0.084    offset: -0.016 m
```